# How to use implement Alea to generate better random numbers

Tags: javascript, random

I am trying to implement http://baagoe.com/en/RandomMusings/javascript/Alea.js onto a website  so I can generate better random numbers, but I can't seem to make it work. The documentation is here: http://baagoe.com/en/RandomMusings/javascript/

The documentation states to call the function like this:

```
var random = Alea();

random(); // returns 0.6198398587293923
```

but it doesn't work.

Even just declaring var random = Alea(); breaks the JavaScript on the page. Is there something I am missing?

Here's the full page I am testing it on:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>javascript test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>example</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
// From http://baagoe.com/en/RandomMusings/javascript/
function Alea() {
  return (function(args) {
    // Johannes BaagÃ¸e <baagoe@baagoe.com>, 2010
    var s0 = 0;
    var s1 = 0;
    var s2 = 0;
    var c = 1;

    if (args.length == 0) {
      args = [+new Date];
    }
    var mash = Mash();
    s0 = mash(' ');
    s1 = mash(' ');
    s2 = mash(' ');

    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
      s0 -= mash(args[i]);
      if (s0 < 0) {
        s0 += 1;
      }
      s1 -= mash(args[i]);
      if (s1 < 0) {
        s1 += 1;
      }
      s2 -= mash(args[i]);
      if (s2 < 0) {
        s2 += 1;
      }
    }
    mash = null;

    var random = function() {
      var t = 2091639 * s0 + c * 2.3283064365386963e-10; // 2^-32
      s0 = s1;
      s1 = s2;
      return s2 = t - (c = t | 0);
    };
    random.uint32 = function() {
      return random() * 0x100000000; // 2^32
    };
    random.fract53 = function() {
      return random() + 
        (random() * 0x200000 | 0) * 1.1102230246251565e-16; // 2^-53
    };
    random.version = 'Alea 0.9';
    random.args = args;
    return random;

  } (Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
};

var random = Alea();

alert('test');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'breaks the page'. be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/PZR4d/)

the problem was you did not include the Mash() function as described in the [article](http://baagoe.com/en/RandomMusings/javascript/) under 'Common implementation details'

Answer (score 0):

Just as an addition to this, I'm not sure I understand the usage correctly. I had thought that is was a replacement for Math.random

The page I created is

```
<html>
<head>
<title>javascript test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>example</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
// From http://baagoe.com/en/RandomMusings/javascript/
// http://baagoe.org/en/wiki/Better_random_numbers_for_javascript
function Alea() {
    return (function(args) {
    // Johannes Baagøe <baagoe@baagoe.com>, 2010
    var s0 = 0;
    var s1 = 0;
    var s2 = 0;
    var c = 1;

    if (args.length == 0) {
      args = [+new Date];
    }
    var mash = Mash();
    s0 = mash(' ');
    s1 = mash(' ');
    s2 = mash(' ');

    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
      s0 -= mash(args[i]);
      if (s0 < 0) {
        s0 += 1;
      }
      s1 -= mash(args[i]);
      if (s1 < 0) {
        s1 += 1;
      }
  s2 -= mash(args[i]);
      if (s2 < 0) {
        s2 += 1;
      }
    }
mash = null;

var random = function() {
  var t = 2091639 * s0 + c * 2.3283064365386963e-10; // 2^-32
  s0 = s1;
  s1 = s2;
  return s2 = t - (c = t | 0);
};
random.uint32 = function() {
  return random() * 0x100000000; // 2^32
};
random.fract53 = function() {
  return random() + 
    (random() * 0x200000 | 0) * 1.1102230246251565e-16; // 2^-53
};
random.version = 'Alea 0.9';
random.args = args;
return random;

} (Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
};

// From http://baagoe.com/en/RandomMusings/javascript/
// Johannes Baagøe <baagoe@baagoe.com>, 2010

function Mash() {
  var n = 0xefc8249d;

  var mash = function(data) {
    data = data.toString();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      n += data.charCodeAt(i);
  var h = 0.02519603282416938 * n;
  n = h >>> 0;
  h -= n;
  h *= n;
  n = h >>> 0;
  h -= n;
  n += h * 0x100000000; // 2^32
}
return (n >>> 0) * 2.3283064365386963e-10; // 2^-32
};

mash.version = 'Mash 0.9';
return mash;
}

var random = Alea();
alert('random = ' + random);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The alert I get says:-

```
random = function() {
  var t = 2091639 * s0 + c * 2.3283064365386963e-10; // 2^-32
  s0 = s1;
  s1 = s2;
  return s2 = t - (c = t | 0);
};
```

Comment: Calling `Alea` returns a function, so you want to do `var random = Alea(); var rand = random(); alert(rand);`.